# saving data from api to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, api

I have the following output from an API:

```
[{'Chapters': {'id': book, 'name': firstbook'}, 'periodPrices': [{'reportDate': '2021-06-01T15:28:00', 'term': '3Q21', 'price': 10.0}, {'reportDate': '2021-06-01T15:28:00', 'term': '4Q21', 'price': 10.0}, {'reportDate': '2021-06-01T15:28:00', 'term': '1Q22', 'price': 10.0}, {'reportDate': '2021-06-01T15:28:00', 'term': '2Q22', 'price': 0.0}, {'reportDate': '2021-06-01T15:28:00', 'term': '3Q22', 'price': 0.0}, {'reportDate': '2021-06-01T15:28:00', 'term': '4Q22', 'price': 0.0}, {'reportDate': '2021-06-01T15:28:00', 'term': '1Q23', 'price': 0.0}, {'reportDate': '2021-06-01T15:28:00', 'term': '2Q23', 'price': 0.0}, {'reportDate': '2021-06-01T15:28:00', 'term': '2H21', 'price': 0.0}, {'reportDate': '2021-06-01T15:28:00', 'term': '1H22', 'price': 0.0}, {'reportDate': '2021-06-01T15:28:00', 'term': '2H22', 'price': 0.0}, {'reportDate': '2021-06-01T15:28:00', 'term': '1H23', 'price': 0.0}, {'reportDate': '2021-06-01T15:28:00', 'term': 'Cal 22', 'price': 0.0}, {'reportDate': '2021-06-01T15:28:00', 'term': 'Cal 23', 'price': 0.0}, {'reportDate': '2021-06-01T15:28:00', 'term': 'Cal 24', 'price': 0.0}]}]
```

I am trying to get the following output in a dataframe:

```
 Date                     id               Term            price      
2021- 06-01T00:00:00      book             3Q21             10.0
2021-06-01T00:00:00       book             4Q21             10.0
2021-06-01T00:00:00       book             1Q22             10.5
etc
```

I tried the following code:

```
l=parsed ###this is the output from API 
df=pd.DataFrame()
for i in l:
   d1 = {}
   reportDate = []
    price = []
 for j in i['Chapters']:
     reportDate.append(j['Date'])
     price.append(j['price'])
 d1['Date'] = reportDate
 d1['Rate'] = price
 df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(d1))
 df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

However, I get the following error: string indices must be integers for the line `for j in i['Chapters']:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with two lines

```
df = pd.DataFrame(l[0]["periodPrices"])
df["id"] = l[0]["Chapters"]["id"]
```

beacuse the [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) method is so powerful!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what the `id` column is needed for.
So see if you can work with this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(l[0]["periodPrices"])
>>> df
             reportDate    term  price
0   2021-06-01T15:28:00    3Q21   10.0
1   2021-06-01T15:28:00    4Q21   10.0
2   2021-06-01T15:28:00    1Q22   10.0
3   2021-06-01T15:28:00    2Q22    0.0
4   2021-06-01T15:28:00    3Q22    0.0
5   2021-06-01T15:28:00    4Q22    0.0
6   2021-06-01T15:28:00    1Q23    0.0
```

You access the main `dict` using `l[0]`.
And then access the `dict` of period prices using `l[0]['periodPrices']`

If you want the `id` column, you can add the following line:

```
df["id"] = l[0]["Chapters"]["id"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = data  ###this is the output from API
df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in l:
    d1 = {}
    reportDate = []
    price = []
for j in i['periodPrices']: # error here
    reportDate.append(j['reportDate']) # error here
    price.append(j['price'])
d1['Date'] = reportDate
d1['Rate'] = price
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(d1))
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```